# How can I show that $P\{|(X-\mu_X)+(Y-\mu_Y)| \ge k\sigma\} \le (2(1+\rho))/k^2$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities

Let $\sigma^2$ be the common variance of the random variables $X$ and $Y$, with their correlation coefficient being $\rho$.

Show that $\forall k>0$, $P\{|(X-\mu_X)+(Y-\mu_Y)| \ge k\sigma\} \le (2(1+\rho))/k^2$.

I know this looks similar to the Chebyshev Inequality: $P\{|X-\mu_x| \ge k\sigma \} \le 1/k^2$. However, I am struggling to find a way to apply Chebyshev's Inequality to show the above inequality. Would I need to use a different inequality, like the covariance inequality or Minkowski Inequality? How many I go about doing this?

Comment: $2(1+\rho)\sigma^2$ is the variance of $Z=X+Y.$  Apply Chebyshev to $Z.$

Comment: This was a great comment. Can I accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to expand on [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber)'s comment (and give you an official answer), suppose you take $Z=X+Y$ and then find the mean and variance of this random variable.  You have mean:

$$\mathbb{E}(Z) = \mathbb{E}(X+Y) = \mathbb{E}(X) + \mathbb{E}(Y) = \mu_X + \mu_Y,$$

and variance:

$$\mathbb{V}(Z) = \mathbb{V}(X+Y) = \mathbb{V}(X) + 2 \cdot \mathbb{C}(X,Y) + \mathbb{V}(Y) = \sigma^2 + 2 \rho \sigma^2 + \sigma^2
= 2(1+\rho) \sigma^2.$$

Applying [Chebychev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) to $Z$ yields the desired inequality.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you!